# How to pass endValue to horizontal annotation in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, web, charts

I am drawing a line chart with `chart.js` and I can't figure out how to pass `endValue` to the horizontal annotation.

I've tried passing any possible value and even changing axis but it doesn't work.

```
annotation: {
    drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw',
    annotations: [{
       type: 'line',
       mode: 'horizontal',
       scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
       value: 0.5,
       endValue: 1,
       borderColor: 'green',
       borderWidth: 4
    },
```

As you can see the line starts at value 0.5 and I want to go only till the next label.

Any help is incredibly helpfull.